# Superkeys of this relation

Tags: normalization, primary-key

I am trying to find the superkeys of this relation, but I am having troubles finding out how many superkeys there are and exactly what they are. I figured out that the candidate keys were {A},{B},{C},{D}.

Here is the relation:

```
R(A,B,C,D)

Functional Dependencies: 

A->B
B->C
C->D
D->A

Candidate keys: {A},{B},{C},{D} (from what I figured out)
```

Can someone please help me find the superkeys, and how exactly to find them?

Comment: How did you find the 4 keys? What is your reasoning?

Comment: Using the closure of attributes for each attribute I attempted, they all showed to contain ABCD (and it is minimal because it has 1 attribute), therefore I concluded they were candidate keys.

Comment: Nice. So you found the candidate keys - which are also the minimal superkeys. A superkey is just a superset of a minimal superkey. In this case, where every attribute is a candidate key itself, every subset of `{A,B,C,D}` - except for the empty set - is a superkey.

Comment: Hi @ypercube , thanks for your prompt response.  So ABCD, ABC, ABD, ACD, AC, AD, etc are all superkeys?  Would A, B, C, or D also be superkeys as well?  Cheers.

Comment: Yes, all 15 combinations, including A, B, C, D..

Comment: Hi @ypercube , how are you counting 15 combinations?

Comment: ABCD (1), ABC, ABD, ACD, BCD (4), AB, AC, ..., CD (6), A, B, C, D (4),  So, 1+4+6+4 = 15. Or 2^4-1 = 15.

Comment: Ah yes, sorry I was redundantly counting the combinations.  I just remembered that in sets, AA or BB etc is the same as just A or B.  Thank you very much for your help.  It does make sense.  I greatly appreciate you taking the time to help me.  Have a good one :)

Comment: Hi @ypercube , I forgot to ask.  Is there a way to find out how many combinations of superkeys there are by using some sort of formula?  Like 2^n where n is the # of attributes, etc?  I hope you can respond again.  Cheers.